# Let function take pointer to template object without specifying template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

This is my situation. I have a class, a template class with an int template parameter, similar to this.

```
template <int n>
class example
{
  bool some_method()
  {
     return n > 1;
  }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is write a function that takes a pointer to an object of this class and uses it. For the things I have to do, there is no need to know the template parameter, the code would look the same for all template parameters. Something like:

```
bool function(example* part1, bool part2)
{
     return part1->some_method() && part2;
}
```

But obviously compiler complains for the lack of template parameters. Any chance I implement such a function without writing a templae function? the example is small, but real life example would be way more verbose and convoluted.

Working on Gcc 4.8.1 with c++11 enabled, https://godbolt.org/z/EXdCe9 example on goldbolt to show the error.

Comment: there is an important difference between a class template and a class. `example` is a template not a class. At runtime there are no templates.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use some form of indirection. The most obvious form in this case would be inheritence and virtual methods:

```
class example_base {
public:
  virtual bool some_method() = 0;
};

template <int n>
class example: public example_base {
public:
  virtual bool some_method() override
  {
     return n > 1;
  }
};

bool function(example_base* part1, bool part2)
{
  return part1->some_method() && part2;
}
```

If you can't (or want to) modify the original class `example`, you could create a wrapper with virtual methods:

```
template <int n>
class example {
public:
  bool some_method()
  {
     return n > 1;
  }
};

class example_wrapper_base {
public:
  virtual bool some_method() = 0;
};

template <int n>
class example_wrapper: public example_wrapper_base {
public:
  example_wrapper_base(example<n>* e): e(e) {}
  virtual bool some_method() override { e->some_method(); }
private:
  example<n>* e;
};

bool function(example_wrapper* part1, bool part2)
{
  return part1->some_method() && part2;
}
```

Comment: Might be a good solution. I already have a superclass but adding another should not be a problem since the functionalities I need are orthogonal. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The function should aslo be a template.

You do this instead, and it compiles on my gcc.

```cpp
template <int n>
class example
{
public:
  bool some_method()
  {
     return n > 1;
  }
};

template<int n>
bool function(example<n>* part1, bool part2)
{
     return part1->some_method() && part2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of adding your answer Yang  But the question said "Any chance I implement such a function without writing a template function?" so I think they knew about this possibility.